# Laravel form request messages not appearing when validation fails

Tags: laravel, laravel-formrequest

[my store method](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ANkqV.png)

[the FormRequest](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3KgBP.png)

the validation is working and I get the confirm message in controller but when the validation fails I get no error messages any advice?

Comment: Are you using AJAX here?

Comment: no, I'm not using Ajax.

Comment: Weird. On your `store` method why are you returning a JSON response?

Comment: sorry I am new to Laravel  , I'm using postman to test my api and when I post my request I get this message back to confirm it ,

Comment: Anyway, the errors should show on the page. Can you share your blade code where you display the errors?

Comment: I am just using postman to test the api that's why I return It in json

Answer (score 1):

You can use validation in controller like this, hopefully it will work for you

```
$validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
        'id' => 'required|string|regex:/(^([A-Z]){2,4}_([0-1]){1}_([0-1]){1}_([0-9]){10})/u'
    ]);
    if ($validator->fails()){
        return (Arr::first(Arr::flatten($validator->messages()->get('*')));
    }
    else{
    //your code
    }
```

Comment: I can use validation in controller with no issue at all , but I want to move my validations to the FormRequest

Comment: i never used form validation but you can take help from laravel offical documentation https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/validation

Answer (score 1):

```
 protected function failedValidation(Validator $validator)
{
    throw new HttpResponseException(response()->json([
        'errors' => $validator->errors(),], 403));
}
```

this worked for me, just needed to return the errors in json format

Comment: It works for my, I think overriding FormRequest method `failedValidation` to return response instead of default redirect to 404 should be an option.